# How can I handle multiple outlook accounts using Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have task to read mails from secondary mail account from outlook using perl.

Comment: This question cannot be answered. You need to provide some example code. Then we can have a look and help you to implement multiple outlook accounts.

Answer (score 0):

---

Please check the following  it may help you.But you should install respective modules.Reference from "http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=916759"

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Mail::POP3Client;
use MIME::QuotedPrint;

my $pop_user = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
my $pop_pass = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
my $pop_host = 'exchange3';

#connect to POP3 sever
my $pop = new Mail::POP3Client    ( HOST => $pop_host );
$pop->User($pop_user);
$pop->Pass($pop_pass);
$pop->Connect() 
    or die "Unable to connect to POP3 server: ".$pop->Message()."\n";

#count number of items in POP3 mailbox                                
my $mailcount = $pop->Count();

for (my $i = 1; $i <= $mailcount ; $i++) {
    my $header = $pop->Head($i); #gets the header
    my $uni = $pop->Uidl($i); # gets the unquie id
    my $body = $pop->Body($i);
    $body = decode_qp($body); #decode quoted printable body
    say "$uni";
    say "$header\n";
    say "$body";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But I am getting Unable to connect to POP3 server: could not connect socket [exchange3, 110]: Invalid argument error

Comment: I feel may be it is due to invalid host name.Check with your hostname@iSampada